# Edge and vertex connectivity of bipartite graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

Let graph $G=(V,E)$ be bipartite graph with partite sets $X = \{x_1, \ldots, x_n\}$ and $Y = \{y_1, \ldots, y_n\}$. Vertices $x_i$ and $y_j$ are connected with edge if and only if $i \neq j$. What would be edge connectivity ($\lambda(G)$) and vertex connectivity($\kappa(G)$) of this graph?

I think that edge connectivity would be $\lambda(G) = 1$ since there are no vertices connected with no more then one edge. But I am not sure, and I don't know vertex connectivity.

Thank you for help

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean that every vertex has precisely $n-1$ neighbours? That would give you $K_{n,n}$ minus one matching.

Comment: @Jernej Yes, I am sure.

Comment: So in this case your graph is a matching which is a disconnected graph for $n > 1.$

Comment: What do you mean by "your graph is matching"? And disconnected graph in terms of edge connectivity or vertex connectivity?

Comment: The graph you describe is the disjoint union of $n$ edges. Hence if $n > 1$ the graph is not connected. But as I said I think you're confused with the definition and in fact want to consider $K_{n,n}$-matching.

Comment: It was bad written. There shouldn't be:connected with exactly one edge bu: connected with edge. I updated my question.

Comment: Do you see that every vertex of this graph has precisely $n-1$ neighbors? How many vertex/edge disjoint paths are between two vertices in $X$. What about a pair of vertices $x \in X,y \in Y$

Comment: Yes I see it.  There shouldn't be any edge between two vertices in $X$ or in $Y$ because graph is bipartite. But I am not sure about a pair of vertices $x$ and $y$.